# RxJS - Do I need to unsubscribe

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, rxjs

If I have something like this:

```
class MyComponent {

  constructor() {

    this.interval = Observbale.interval(1000);

  }
}

const c = new MyComponent();
const subscription = c.interval.subscribe(() => { ... })
```

Now let's say that at a certain point I'm doing this:

```
c = null;
```

I still need to call `subscription.unsubscribe()` before or the GC will take care for this "leak"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You need to call `unsubscribe` on the returned subscription.

Internally, there is a call to `window.setInterval` and its implementation will hold a reference to the observable. Setting your reference to `null` will have no affect on this, so the observable will not be collected and the function passed to `subscribe` will continue to be called.

In general, if you subscribe to an observable, that observable will continue to call the `next` function that was passed to `subscribe` - unless the observable completes or errors.

If you want the observable to stop calling the `next` function and to release any resources associated with the subscription - including resources referenced from within the `next` function - you *must* call `unsubscribe`.

The only situations in which observables will release resources without an `unsubscribe` call are when observables complete or error.

Comment: And if I have an observable that does not complete but does not use interval ,like this.store.select() from ngrx

Comment: If you subscribe to any observable that neither completes nor errors, you *must* unsubscribe to clean things up. That's part of the contact.

Comment: I understand this, but I can't understand why. If I have something like this: store.select('state').subscribe(() => // ) why I need to unsubscribe if the component is destroyed. The whole question is why it is not a valid object for GC?

Comment: For the same reason as with the `interval` observable mentioned in the question: the observable to which you've subscribed as a reference to the function passed to `subscribe` and it will keep calling it until it's told not to. And that function likely has a reference to said component.

Comment: OK, you can add this to the answer to be more clear about any observable and not for the specific case of the interval so I can mark this as the answer.

Comment: Sure, I've added a more general explanation.