# Unsubscribe an Observable in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection 'regularItems' in firestore,to get the data i am using the code

```
  ionViewDidLoad(){
      this.fa().then(snapShot=>{ 
          snapShot.subscribe((data:MM[])=>{
              for(const d in data){
               var x= (this.afs.collection(`regularItem/${data[d].itemCategory}/category`).valueChanges());
                x.forEach(d=>{
                   d.forEach(dd=>{
                       this.c.push(dd);
                   })
               })
              }

          });
      })
    }
```

as you can see in the code i am subscribing to 'snapShot' to get the data;
i can access the data without any problem;

My question is, is it necessary to unsubscribe a subscription;
if yes how can i do that..?
is there any problem if i don't unsubscribe subscription?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJS - Do I need to unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44536497/rxjs-do-i-need-to-unsubscribe)